# xdvipdfmx error with \slash followed by zero-width space set in Times

Tags: xetex, xdvipdfmx

I’m trying to compile this document—

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % no-math can be omitted
\setmainfont{Times}
\begin{document}
\slash\char"200B
\end{document}
```

—using XeTeX (3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014)). That’s a `\slash`, which is defined at line 467 of latex.ltx as—

```
\def\slash{/\penalty\exhyphenpenalty} % a `/' that acts like a `-'
```

—followed by a zero-width space (U+200B), all set in Times. I’m including `no-math` because the error that results is the same as in this [xdvipdfmx error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219960/xdvipdfmx-error), but including (or omitting) `no-math` does not resolve the error. Since this is XeTeX, I could insert the zero-width space directly, but I’m using `\char` for clarity.

If I run `xetex -fmt xelatex document.tex`, I get this error message:

```
xdvipdfmx:fatal: CID count > 65535

Output file removed.
 )
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file document.pdf may not be valid
```

This arose from converting an HTML document to TeX. The actual HTML contains something like `more/&#8203;bacon`, the important part being the slash followed by `&#8203;`, the decimal numeric character reference for a zero-width space. I convert plain slashes in HTML to `\slash{}` in TeX, and that’s how I ended up with a `\slash` followed by a zero-width space.

How does this issue come about, and how can I work around it? For what it’s worth, I can completely remove zero-width spaces from the TeX I produce.

(For the sake of completeness, if I use `/\char"200B` instead of `\slash\char"200B`, a PDF file is produced as expected. Using a font other than Times also seems to resolve the error, but I can’t change the font in my particular case. Running `luatex --fmt lualatex document.tex` also works, but I’d like to avoid switching TeX engines if possible.)

Comment: It's not `\slash` that produces the issue: I get the same error even with `\char"200B` alone in the document.

Comment: Do you get the same error with `/\char"200B`?

Comment: No, with just `\char"200B` in the document body. Another example is `x\penalty0\char"200B`. However, redefining `\slash` to mean `/\discretionary{}{}{}` seems to cure the problem. The penalty emitted is not the same, however.

Comment: Indeed, I can get the error with the plain file `\font\test="Times Roman/AAT"\test\char"200B \bye`.

Comment: I guess it's a problem with `.dfont` and `.ttc` font files.